# Macos thinks a charger is connected when none is

Tags: battery, charging, power, charger

I'm seeing a curious issue where my MBP (running Catalina 10.15.7) is showing an AC Charger connected when none is.

- I'm seeing this happen with multiple USB-C chargers, and not seeing those same chargers have issues with other MBPs.
- Another potential clue is that I've stopped hearing any chimes when plugging in or unplugging chargers.

From System Information:

```
AC Charger Information
  
Connected:  Yes
  ID:   0x0000
  Wattage (W):  86
  Family:   0xe0004008
  Charging: No
```

And from `pmset` directly:

```
$ pmset -g ac
 Wattage = 86W
 Current = 4300mA
 Voltage = 20000mV
 AdapterID = 0
 Family Code = 0xe0004008
```

When I *do* plug in a charger, I can see `pmset` update a few seconds later and show the proper charger info:

```
$ pmset -g ac
 Wattage = 94W
 Current = 4700mA
 Voltage = 20000mV
 AdapterID = 28674
 Manufacturer = Apple Inc.
 Family Code = 0xe0004009
 Serial String = C4XXXXXXXXXXX
 Adapter Name = 96W USB-C Power Adapter
 Hardware Version = 1.0
 Firmware Version = 01070051
```

Anyone seen this before, have a hunch what may be happening, or suggestions of where to look next? Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) It'd be good to know the actual model of MBP your question is about. Also, have you tried [resetting the SMC](https://support.apple.com/HT201295)?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like something isn't being recognised correctly, because when you are running the MacBook on battery and run `pmset -g ac` you should get a message `No adapter attached.`. Resetting the SMC should reset power-related settings/sensors. Let us know if this doesn't fix it for you :)